# Configure route in a Blazor Server-Side client project

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm making a Blazor server-side SPA client app which communicate with API controllers on a MVC server through HTTP requests.

What should I add in both `Startup.cs` of the client and server to make the routing work when making the HTTP request ?
And how can I configure the routes ?

Comment: "how can I configure the routes" : which routes?  Client or Server?

Comment: Well, as my problem evolved a bit, I'm trying now to find how to configure my MVC server so it would use my Blazor server-side app. I added the `app.UseServerSideBlazor<Client.Startup>()` to my `Configure` method but I don't see how to add a `MapFallback` of my Blazor server-side into my MVC configuration.

Comment: A server does not 'use an app'.  An app can use a server.

Comment: And if you just want to serve up the client app, that is built in the templates. UseStaticFiles() handles it.

Comment: It's still very unclear what type of app you want to make and what your problem is. Server side Blazor _is_ an Asp.Net server, it can host an API (on the side) or be a client to any other API server. Nothing special to be setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK... The BlazingPizza sample is a Blazor WebAssembly application. It is executed on the client browser. The solution contains three projects: Shared (shared by the other two projects); Client ( executed on the client browser); and Server (a project which host the application and the Web Api). Now, you want to convert this application to Blazor Server app, right ?

Do this and you're safe:
1. Go to Visual Studio and create Blazor Server App (from the Create a new Blazor app dialog). After hitting the "Create" button, a new Server-side Blazor application is created and configured for you. Run this app and see what it can do, view the Startup class to learn how your app was configured, etc.

Realize this: This is an Asp.Net Core app, running on the server, and sending Html content via SignaleR to connected clients. It is important that you realize that this (the Html you see in the browser) is the client-side of the Blazor Server app, but execution of code occurs on the server only,and thus, if you use a Web Api app to your application, it is executed on the server; in other words, from the server you make Web Api calls to the server. This is legitimate, and sometimes even necessary...

2. To add a Web Api project to your application do the following: Right click on the solution name, select *Add* --> *New Project*... From the Add a new project window select Asp.Net Core Web Application. From the Create a new Asp.Net Core web application window select the API project template, and then hit the "Create" button. A new Web Api project is created and configured for you with a controller named WeatherForecastController.
3. You are going to call the Web Api endpoint from your Blazor Server app, right ?
   So add a reference to the Web Api project from the Blazor Server app. Now you 
   can perform HTTP calls from your Blazor Server to the Web Api endpoints.

What I've described above is how you do what you've asked in the comment above. But this is only the beginning. Start to play with it, and please, if you have more questions, open new question threads, and I'll try to help...

Comment: Thanks a lot man, your answer makes me understand so much more now. I got so confused with all the tutorial and explanations that were more or less outdated that I started experimating to understand how to do it. Is this the recommanded way to do things or I should just put my Web API controllers into the Blazor server-side project for simplicity ?

Comment: In the above answer I've shown you how to create a server-side Blazor app that make HTTP calls to Web Api endpoints because this was your request. If you're asking whether to use Web Api with server-side Blazor, then my answer, already expressed in the answer above and below, is that it depends on solution you have to provide. Again, generally speaking, it's more reasonable to use local services rather than Web Api, as both the Blazor Server App and the Web Api reside on the server.

Comment: As I said, I got lots of things wrong so I want to be sure this time on the way to do things. But this is already really helpful, thank you again.

Comment: Incidentally, I'd recommend you to learn the basics of Blazor first, by creating smaller apps. Stick to the docs. As for other sources, the only one I know that is good, and I heartily suggest you visit and read and practice all the articles, is the web site by chris chainty.  I've started learning Blazor there.  Good luck.